# Three.js - Mesh with fewer morph targets be affected by one with more morph targets?

Tags: javascript, three.js

As title, it's so weird that the Object3D with fewer morph targets will be affected by another one with more morph targets.

I duplicated the error [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jhclaura/bvvpx40j/8/) by adding a cube with 4 morph targets into Three.js official example [webgl_morphtargets](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets). The original example only has one cube with 8 morph targets.

In the example, top 8 input bars change the morphTargetInfluences of gray cube, and bottom 4 bars change the blue cube. Two cubes have different geometries and materials, but adjusting the top 8 input bars affects the blue cube.

The part of morphTargets codes were pasted below. Have been troubled by this for days and couldn't figure it out. Any guidance will be much appreciated, thanks!

```
            // first cube
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, morphTargets: true } );

            // construct 8 blend shapes
            for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i ++ ) {
                var vertices = [];
                for ( var v = 0; v < geometry.vertices.length; v ++ ) {
                    vertices.push( geometry.vertices[ v ].clone() );
                    if ( v === i ) {
                        vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].x *= 2;
                        vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].y *= 2;
                        vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].z *= 2;
                    }
                }
                geometry.morphTargets.push( { name: "target" + i, vertices: vertices } );
            }
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );

            // second cube
            var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );
            var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff, morphTargets: true } );

            // construct 4 blend shapes
            for ( var i = 0; i < geometry2.vertices.length/2; i ++ ) {
                var vertices = [];
                for ( var v = 0; v < geometry2.vertices.length; v ++ ) {
                    vertices.push( geometry2.vertices[ v ].clone() );
                    if ( v === i ) {
                        vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].x *= 2;
                        vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].y *= 2;
                        vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].z *= 2;
                    }
                }
                geometry2.morphTargets.push( { name: "target" + i, vertices: vertices } );
            }
            geometry2.computeMorphNormals();
            mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
            mesh2.position.x = 200;
            scene.add( mesh2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug and it's solved in the new library now.